# Is there way to check if a user has clicked on button in a window opened by JS?

Tags: javascript

I am working on a project. If a user subscribe, like or watch a video for some time they get bonus points.

I have tried to open the video in a new tab or window and then try to insert some js code to check if they have subscribed or liked the video.

But the alert function doesn't run. not sure why.

Is there a way to check If a user has clicked on subscribed or not?

```js
document.getElementById('watch-video').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  const videoWindow = window.open(
    'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CM4CkVFmTds',
    'Youtube Video',
    'width=800,height=600,resizable,scrollbars'
  );

  videoWindow.onload = function () {
    alert('Hi there');
  };
});
```

```html
<button id="watch-video">Watch Video</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no possible way of doing that because you loose the control as it is opened in a new window and is a different website altogether.

Comment: ah, ok. I'll try to do it with the browser extension then

Comment: That might work, but might have privacy issues.